# Settings in functions.php used by a plugin

Tags: functions, filters, actions, options, globals

I'm writing a simple plugin and want some settings in an array in the functions.php file.

**I'm thinking of adding this in the theme functions.php**

```
$test = array('haha' => 'hehe');
my_function( $test);
```

However I need to fetch it by actions and filters in the plugin. For example I have a function like this:

```
add_action('wp_head', 'tryit');
function tryit() {
    print_r($test);
}
```

I need it to put the $test array in there. Global variables are bad. Is it possible with do_action, add_action, do_filter, apply filter somehow? Example?

Comment: May this would help. Check second answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13282503/how-do-i-pass-a-variable-to-an-action-hook-function

Answer (score 0):

On top of my head scheme like this should work:

```
// functions.php

function prefix_get_settings() {
    return array('haha' => 'hehe');
}

add_filter( 'prefix_default_settings', 'prefix_get_settings', 9 );


// plugin

$default_settings = apply_filters( 'prefix_default_settings', array() );
```